# Can't send email from application

Tags: android

Can some body help me to understand why my application don't send simple email to predefined adress? There is my code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailServer});

String subject = (String) reasonVariants.getSelectedItem();
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                             userComment.getText().toString());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Looks like good, but I don't recive any messages to my mail(mailServer).

Answer (score 0):

Did you look inside your Spam folder? ;-)

Maybe the Email was send successfully but it got lost/deleted/spam-filtered somewhere in the delivery line. Try the sending process in a network, where you can trace the traffic and look there if the mail is really being send.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I've cheched spam folder, but it also empty :-(
I think maybe I have some problems with my mail account on the phone???

Comment: Can you send emails with the build in email application?

Answer (score 0):

My idea about wront account settings was right. After some time spended me in MailSender setting's on the phone my project, at last :-), began send mail. So, to finish this discussion I can say onle one - for successful sending e-mail's in Android you must have correctly configurated e-mail client.